# Embedding custom binary file inside my app using XCode 6

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I would like to embed a custom binary file inside my app (for example: level information for a game that, for practical purposes, cannot be encoded in any other way).

Is there a way to do this with XCode 6 and Swift? I have tried asset catalogs, but they seem to only allow images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple:

1. Create a group (this is optional, but tidier)
2. Drag the file into the group

The file can be accessed in Swift with:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename_without_extension", ofType: "ext")
```

which returns a `String?` with the file's path.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone looking for the code using xcode 9.
This is it:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename_without_extension", ofType: "hex")
```